# Where is the D&D 3.5 random loot table?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, treasure

This should be easy -- however I've gone through three books trying to find it. What book and page number is the random loot per level table for 3.5 edition?

I saw it a couple months ago and didn't bookmark it.

Comment: You should really clarify what you mean by a "random loot per level table".  There are tables for generating random loot, and tables that tell you how much loot a PC should get (on average) per level.  But no tables I know of that give "random loot per level".  (Perhaps in the magic item compendium?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Table 3-5: Treasure](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/treasure.htm) starts on page 52 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*.